# google navigation is not working on android operating system for an asp.net application

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, google-maps

I have asp.net bootstrap based mobile application running android tablet.I am using following code on javascript file to open google navigation,but no luck at all,Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

```
function startGoogleNavigation(X, Y) {
    var MapURL = "google.navigation:q=" + Y+ "," + X+ "&mode=d";
    window.open(MapURL, '_system');
}
```

Is there any special port need to be opened??but maps.google.comis working on tablet

Comment: What happens if you replace this URL scheme with Google Maps URLs? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Comment: there is some connectivity issue from our vmwire browser to maps